# How do I change the ArcGIS Server Web Adaptor name?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-web-adaptor

If I decide I want to change the Web Adaptor name, is it as simple as going to the Web Adapter tab in the Server Manager and clicking unregister?

And then would I just rerun the Web Adaptor install and choose a different name?

Or what is the proper way of changing Web Adaptor names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the ESRI Resources page: [About the ArcGIS Web Adaptor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_the_ArcGIS_Web_Adaptor/01540000028p000000/) to get all the information you need.

It looks like you can name it anything you want, as long as that name isn't already in use somewhere else.